# How would you architect on Azure a massive record import from CSV?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-blob-storage

Let's suppose once a day you want to import data in a target system A from a source system B, to do so B creates a CSV file F with all data to be transferred and an automatic procedure reads F and creates all data in A.

**How would you architect this simple task in Azure with no use of Virtual Machine?**

- In plain old styles I would do something like this: B stores the file in a folder of a Server and a scheduled task reads the file and import all data, but this option needs a Server o Virtual Machine both for the file storage and the scheduled task.
- A micro service option could be that B stores F in a Blob Container and an Azure Function reads the file and import all data, but this can incur in the 2 minutes limit of the Azure function.

How would you approach this simple task?

Answer (score 0):

The tool for the job would be Azure Data Factory that runs on a schedule. It's trivial to setup if the source file F is uploaded to Blob storage. However, I'm not sure how cost-effective this is.

To get around the 2 minute limit of an Azure function, you could choose to go for Container Instances.
You can make a small container that has the following container settings:

- BLOB_SAS_URL (B)
- TARGET_CONNECTION_STRING (A)

The application in that container reads data from the CSV, and writes it to the target. When done, the application (and thus the container) should exit.

You can set the restart policy of the container to 'never', so it will run (and cost money) only during the execution. You can then start the container daily.

Answer (score 0):

I would either use Azure Durable functions to remove the 2 minutes limitations or use Azure Batch service depending on how massive and how time-critical is the processing of the file.

In the case of AF, I would upload file to blob storage, then trigger orchestration function via HTTP trigger (after file completes uploading), and the orchestration would call activity functions to process the data, provide the webhook for progress updates and for job cancellation.

And if this is truly a massive scale, then I would use the same pattern but instead of using AF for processing, I would use it to split files into smaller parts and schedule Azure Batch jobs to process it.